# Can the Johnson-Neyman moderation interaction technique be used with a categorical moderator?

Tags: regression, interaction

Can the Johnson-Neyman moderation interaction technique be used with a categorical moderator (3 categories)? 60%, 80% and 100%.

I am guessing that it could approximate the interaction effect at hypothetical values of the moderator. Although I have three groupings of the moderator, the moderator in reality is continuous.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but the whole point of the JN method is to find the regions of significance for a quantitative moderator. I think if you already have decided on those regions, then you can simply use ANOVA to group the samples by the moderator value and analyis the bivariate correlation between the other two parties.